# Find count of logged in users in Active Directory

Tags: c#, windows, active-directory

*EDIT START*

I found a PSLOGGEDON.exe that finds who is logged into a particular computer (locally/remotely). How can I use this exe and input it list of computer names and see how many computers are there on which some one is logged in?

## EDIT END

How can I find the # of users logged in to a particular Active Directory domain?

Using the below code I can get list of all the Active directory users but how can I use this to know which users are logged in?

```
    using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "yourdomain.com"))
{
    using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
    {
        foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
        {
            DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
            Console.WriteLine("First Name: " + de.Properties["givenName"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine("Last Name : " + de.Properties["sn"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine("SAM account name   : " + de.Properties["samAccountName"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine("User principal name: " + de.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: AD only stores the *static* properties of your network - it doesn't keep track of the logged in users at any given time

Comment: @marc_s not event just the count of logged in users?

Comment: AD doesn't store that informatoin